# How to create script to field output all frame in ABAQUS?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I am a newbie in Python scripting I have numerous odb files. I want to export displacement and reaction force from all the odb files to excel. For that I am trying to write a python script. I have written following script but It is ending up with an error.

```
path = './'from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from optimization import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import random
from array import *
from odbAccess import openOdb
import odbAccess
import math
import numpy    
import os        # Operating system
import shutil    # copying or moving files
import numpy as np

# import database
odbname = 'BR_70_25mm-45HRD-F'
odb = session.openOdb(name = 'BR_70_25mm-45HRD-F.odb')
odb = session.odbs['BR_70_25mm-45HRD-F.odb']

part_instance = odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['M_SET-5']
for key in keys:
   step = odb.steps[key]
   frameRepository = step.frames
   if len(frameRepository):
        for frame in frameRepository:
            print 'Id = %d, Time = %f\n'%(frame.frameId,frame.frameValue)
            fo = frame.fieldOutputs
            f1 = fo['U']
            f2 = fo['RF']
            HRF3 = np.array(f1)
            HU3 = np.array(f2)
            FD = np.hstack((HU3,HRF3))
            np.savetxt(path + odbname + '.csv', FD, delimiter=',')
```

It is showing an error as

> File "C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.13-1\tools\SMApy\python2.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\io.py", line 786, in savetxt
> fh.write(format % tuple(row) + '\n')
> TypeError: float argument required, not FieldOutput

Can anyone please help me with this, so that with this script I can easily export the displacements and reaction force to excel file.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, the error is caused by the `f1` variable. It is an object from the `FieldOutput` class. Numpy only converts `array_like` objects (see more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)) and this is why the command `HRF3 = np.array(f1)` fails.

I suggest you use tools from the Abaqus/CAE through the script. For example:

```py
import os

from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from visualization import *


# Set work directory
os.chdir("path/to/folder/with/odb/file")

# Import database
odbname = "DamageZone"
odb = session.openOdb(name=odbname + ".odb")

# Information to be read
output_info = (("U", NODAL), ("RF", NODAL))
nodes_info = (("PART-1-1", (41, 7616)), ("PART-1-1", (15, 7576)))

# XYData creation
data = session.xyDataListFromField(
    odb=odb,
    outputPosition=NODAL,
    variable=output_info,
    nodeLabels=nodes_info,
)

# Saving the results
file_name = "Results" + ".rpt"
session.writeXYReport(fileName=file_name, xyData=data, appendMode=False)

# Delete the created XYData
for d in data:
    del session.xyDataObjects[d.legendLabel]
```

It creates XYData of all components of the nodal outputs (defined in `output_info`) through all frames of all steps for the selected nodes (defined in `nodes_info`).

In the end, the results are saved in a text file called "Results.rpt". You can copy the content and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet. To format it, you can click in "Text to Columns" in Excel (Data > Data Tools > Text to Columns), select the field "Fixed width", and click on "Finish".

I suggest you run this script from the Abaqus/CAE interface (File > Run Script). In some machines, this script can fail if run by the command line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and help. Can I add node set name in nodes_info instead of part name and its number. By the way (41, 7616) are these x y coordinates of the point?

Comment: Try to create a node set with the node(s) you need. For example the node set `my_nset`. You can access the nodes with `my_nodes = odb.rootAssembly.instances["PART-1-1"].nodeSets["my_nset"].nodes`.